# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B no image

Tags: boot, hdmi, screen

I've just purchased a Raspberry Pi Model B, I've installed NOOBS latest version after I've formatted card with SD card formatter. Problem is when I'm booting it appears the menu to install Raspbian, but after 2 seconds my monitor (Benq 17" or 18" almost square display) start blinking it goes black after 1 second it appears menu for installing Raspbian and after 2-3 cycles it doesn't show anything.

I am using an HDMI to VGA adapter.

Comment: How is the Pi connected to the monitor? How is the Pi powered? have you tried a different cable (video)?

Comment: pi is powered by an amp with 5V and 2A. To monitor is conected via an Hdmi to VGA adapter

Comment: You need to try without the adapter (i.e., a direct HDMI connection) in order to rule that out, as it is almost certainly the culprit.  Those adapters can require power from the input and I believe the pi is not equiped to handle this.

Comment: i have a friend who is using same adapter and charger and is working

Comment: I heard about someone who survived falling 30k ft. from a plane doesn't mean I should try it. Trying it without the adapter is the only way to properly diagnose the problem.

Comment: I know this may not be incredibly helpful but there are a number of settings you can try in the config.txt, https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md check out the section marked "WHICH VALUES ARE VALID FOR MY MONITOR?". I have successfully used HDMI-VGA adapters with various Pi and found a an external powered USB hub made a big difference, not self powering the Pi.